# Stored procedure with table valued parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a stored procedure that uses a table as input parameter. However it is not working as intended. Steps I've taken:

First I make a user defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE y_yhat_tabletype AS TABLE
(
    UTC_DT datetime,
    y  float,
    yhat float
);
```

Then I try to make a stored procedure:

```
create procedure sp_evaluate_y_yhat 
    @data y_yhat_tabletype readonly
    as
    begin
        select sum(@data.y) as sum_y, sum(@data.yhat) as sum_yhat
    end
```

But I get the error:

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_evaluate_y_yhat, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
Must declare the scalar variable "@data".
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_evaluate_y_yhat, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
Must declare the scalar variable "@data".
```

The `select sum(@data.y) as sum_y, sum(@data.yhat) as sum_yhat` line is just to get some output while testing and will be replaced with more operations as soon as I get this to work.

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

`@data` is essentially a table, so you need to treat it as such.

Declare as:

```
create procedure sp_evaluate_y_yhat
( 
    @data y_yhat_tabletype readonly
)
as
    begin
        select sum(y) as sum_y, sum(yhat) as sum_yhat
        from @data
    end
go
```

It's worth noting that if `@data` contained many rows, the row estimate might be off as table variables don't get statistics.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, the problem did not come from what I put between `begin` and `end`. It comes from the database not recognising y_yhat_tabletype as a tabletype despite it showing up in the folder `user-defined table types` under programmability > types. When I copy paste your query into SSMS I get the following error message when I mouse-over the line `@data y_yhat_tabletype readonly`: "The parameter @data cannot be declared READONLY since it is not a table-valued parameter". Any idea why it might say this?

Comment: I posted the code in sql server, and it worked.

Comment: You're right, it does work despire the crinkly red line underlining `@data y_yhat_tabletype readonly`

Comment: @XiB that’s just a parsing warning due to IntelliSense being dense. CTRL+Shift+R should refresh the local cache and make the big bad squiggly go away.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for showing me this neat shortcut and helping me understand the source of my big bad squiggly!